# Edit CSS Menu show submenu on click not hover?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this menu https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/bVbEbJ and it works well, but I'm trying to work out how to only show the sub menu fly out when a menu item is clicked not hovered over.

So far I've added the class '.has-sub-entries' to the 'a href' menu items and using jQuery I've added an on click event. In the CSS I've set the '.nav-flyout' class to have `display:none` and that stops the sub menu showing.

I'm now trying to work out how to show it when I click the menu item.

Any ideas on this ?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to do that is to use the checkbox hack. It works by attaching a label to an <input type="checkbox"> element via the label's for="" attribute.

i have tried to do that by this code https://codepen.io/wmizxqve/pen/poOLpxw   you can enhance it

Comment: Thanks :) I'll test this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me.  Anyone any other ideas ?

Comment: i will try to check by today,